# Sliding using Swiper API, doesn't swipe on first attempt in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, swiper.js

I built a quick just-image slider for a presentation about Hungary.
Desktop version is fine, tested on iPhone 4 it's fine, but when we
test it on iPhone 6 the swipe function won't work.

This is only happening on first attempt, if we rotate the device and rotate back, the swiping is back in business. But it will be viewed by customers, so if they can't use it properly on first attempt, they might just close it and won't try again.

I'm using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/) for this slider.

[link to my slider](http://alphahungary.com/presentation/hungary.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you init Swiper when it is "display:none" (in mobile Portrait mode). Don't do that, or call it's ".update(true)" method when you make it visible again